# Rendering Hyperlink in VF page

Tags: visualforce, rendered

In a page block table based on a condition, I want to render some values as hyperlink and other as plain text.
I am able to achieve the above requirement as below:

```
  <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(a.AccessLevel__c != 'Full',true,false)}" value="{!a.Name}"></apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(a.AccessLevel__c == 'Full',true,false)}" value="/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:column>
```

I want to know is there a better way of doing it from VF page without changing the logic in class

Comment: I think it is good. I also used the same piece of code earlier when it required. If you want to do with another approach then apply the CSS conditionally. In this use only <apex:outputLink ../> and apply css of hyperlink when it will treat as link otherwise css of plain text.

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj Disadvantage with CSS is that it still gets rendered to the page and a savvy user might be able to dig it out. I believe using the `rendered` attribute does not leave that possibility open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is fine.

Your merge logic, however, violates a basic axiom of `Boolean` logic:

> You can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

In your case, it should be:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!a.AccessLevel__c != 'Full'}" ...>
<apex:outputLink rendered="{!a.AccessLevel__c == 'Full'}" ...>
```

---

Another minor cleanup is that you can build the link itself more programmatically.

Instead of:

```
<apex:outputLink ... value="/{!a.id}">
```

it is arguably cleaner to use:

```
<apex:outputLink ... value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, a.id)}">
```

Comment: value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, a.id)}" is not working (Nothing displaying)

Comment: Hmm if it doesn't yield anything, just stick with what you've got then. It's worth trying when building links though.